# Every moment it gets or every moment gets

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am watching an NHS video at the moment, and a female reporter said that she was about to cry when she heard the first line of the NHS choir... and she said:

> "When they sang I immediately, nearly when I was like gonna cry, I could feel my bottom lip and I was getting that wobbly chin **every moment it gets/ every moment gets** and I thought and said ''you can't cry on day 1 of practice, hold it together'' and on and on...
>
> (not exactly the words just mostly)

Every moment gets/it gets is a bit idiomatic(UK) right? and can't find it on google. Anyway, which is correct?

Here's the link(starts at 7-7.30)
https://youtu.be/qs-sNKvC730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misheard. What she actually said was:

"I was getting that wobbly chin *that my mum gets*"

The broadcaster is Sara Cox, she speaks with quite a strong *northern* accent. I'm from the north of England myself so I have no problem understanding this (although my accent isn't like that!)

So what she was trying to say was that she reacted with emotion in a way that her own mother reacts. There is no assumption that we should know how her mother reacts to this kind of thing. It could just be a throwaway comment for comedy effect, implying that when she was lost in her emotions she reminded herself of her own mother.

Comment: Yes that's Sara Cox! (though I only looked that up just a very few hours ago hehe). I see... so that's what northerners sound like huh, cheers mate

Comment: @JohnArvin Not all northerners! She's from Bolton though, very strong accent.

Answer (score -3):

They're all incomplete sentences, so not 'proper' English really, - just rambling words rather than phrases.

I haven't watched to the video but all of those phrases could be used in a full sentences (although gets is the wrong tense)
-I was getting that wobbly-chin moment.
-Every moment it (the atmosphere) was getting more and more emotional 
-Every moment I was getting more and more emotional